# Delay from OSX "installer"

Tags: macos, installation

I have the following script to install a Mac package from terminal:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -d /Applications/XX.app ]; then
    hdiutil mount XX.dmg
    cd /Volumes/XX
    sudo installer -pkg XX.pkg -target /
    cd ..
    hdiutil unmount XX
fi
```

Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes it ended up with error:

```
hdiutil: unmount: "XX" failed to unmount due to error 49168.
hdiutil: unmount failed - Resource busy
```

Actually, after several seconds, XX becomes unmountable. I realize that this may be due to a delay from "installer", which was not done yet when calling "unmount XX". Is there anyway to synchronize between "installer" and "unmount"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the "installer" command manual and not found a direct solution to
avoid this synchronizing issue.

The solution I came up with is that, after stepping out of "installer", I
will keep query the status from "hdiutil unmount" every other second until
a normal termination signal is achieved, i.e.:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -d /Applications/XX.app ]; then
    hdiutil mount XX.dmg
    cd /Volumes/XX
    sudo installer -pkg XX.pkg -target /
    cd ..
    flag=1
    while [ $flag -ne 0 ]
        do
            sleep 1
            hdiutil unmount XX
            flag=$?
        done
fi
```

I know this may not be the best solution, and I look forward to more elegant alternatives.